# Load custom translation in custom plugin fails

Tags: plugin-development, translation, multi-language, language

I'm working on a custom plugin and I try to add translations but without any success

```
   class MyClass
    {
       public function __construct()
       {
         add_action('plugins_loaded', [$this, 'ausg_langs_i18n'] );
       }

    /**
     * Trying to load plugins locales
     */
    public function ausg_langs_i18n()
    {
        $plugin_rel_path = BASE_PATH . 'lang';
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'ausg', false, $plugin_rel_path );

    }
}
```

on plugin init the text domain is set to `ausg` the `.mo` file is generated with PoEdit.

if I var_dump `load_plugin_textdomain( 'ausg', false, $plugin_rel_path )` the result is false

How to debug further this issue?

**Update**

```
     define('BASE_LANG_DIR', basename(__DIR__) . '/lang');

     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->lang = $this->setLangGlobal();

        add_action('plugins_loaded', [$this, 'ausg_langs_i18n'] );

    }

  public function ausg_langs_i18n()
    {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'ausg', false, BASE_LANG_DIR );
    }
```

here is the wronhg path output `Warning: MO file not found at /var/www/my-plugin/web/app/languages/plugins/ausg-en_US.mo`

Comment: What is `BASE_PATH` set to? If you dump `$plugin_rel_path` do you get the correct path?

Comment: Yes I get the correct absolute path to the plugin base directory

Comment: Well [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/) for `load_plugin_textdomain()` states that `$plugin_rel_path` is supposed to be "Relative path to WP_PLUGIN_DIR where the .mo file resides.". So you shouldn't be passing the absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, debuging the issue with the provided hook from @Tim I see that wordpress tries to pick up the mo files from wrong path. However I defined the relative path as you suggested

Comment: That isn't the "wrong" path. WordPress looks there *first*, and then tries the path you give. Sounds like it's working as expected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Jacob has probably solved your problem in the comments.

However, to your question:

> How to debug further this issue?

I would hook into the [load_textdomain_mofile](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load_textdomain_mofile/) filter and check the fully built file paths WordPress is actually trying to read: Example:

```
<?php
function debug_missing_mofile( $mofile, $domain ){
   if( 'ausg' === $domain && ! is_readable($mofile) ){
       trigger_error('MO file not found at '.$mofile, E_USER_WARNING);
   }
   return $mofile;
}
add_filter('load_textdomain_mofile','debug_missing_mofile',999,2);
```

You should get two warnings. First for a missing file under WP_LANG_DIR, Second for a missing file that is probably your incorrect plugin path.

Notes:

- Up to you how you print the error. This example just raises a warning.
- Hooking with low priority to ensure other filters modifying paths have run.